# Node + AngularJS ngRoute not displaying correct view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am running a test Node server using this JS that I will post below.  My main problem is this:  I am creating a route ('/login') using Angulars' ngRoute, but it is not displaying the correct templateUrl when I access the route?  Check my code below.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    apiRouter = require('./app/routes/api.js');

mongoose.connect('localhost', 'triviaattack');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(apiRouter);
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
    next();
});

app.listen(1337);

console.log('\033[2J');
console.log('Server started!');
```

As you can see, I have a Node router external file api.js containing some API routes.  And everything else I have a catchall that returns /public/index.html, here is that file which loads angular, angular-route, and my angular app.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./app/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
        <a href="/login" ng-if="!loginData.isLoggedIn">Login!</a>
        <p ng-if="loginData.isLoggedIn">Welcome, you are logged in as {{ loginData.username }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here, finally, is my small test angular app, which is referenced in index.html above using the relative path ./app/app.js

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);

myApp.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.loginData = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        isLoggedIn: false
    }
}]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', 
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/login', { //Doesn't show!?!?!?!
            templateUrl: './app/views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        });
}]);

console.log('app.js loaded!');
```

Comment: you could try using the `$stateProvider` instead of route provider. I found that much easier to use

Comment: there is no `<ng-view>` in your main page. That's where router will put templates

Comment: @JoeLloyd Thanks for the advice, I just don't see that solution on the angular documentation here:  https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: @charlietfl I added an empty div with the ng-view directive below the div currently in index.html, but then I navigate to /login, the login.html templateUrl is not loading still.

Comment: @DavidStampher here is a link to some code of mine, it has the `$stateProvider` https://github.com/joeLloyd/Scripto5000/blob/master/CordovaApp/CordovaApp/js/app.js

Comment: Inspect the ajax request for template in dev tools network tab to see if it is succeeding. Any errors thrown? Does url stay on `login` even though template not showing?

Comment: @JoeLloyd I will look into it if I can't get this working.  For now I would like to use $routeProvider to accomplish this simply because thats what they are using in the Angular documentation.  So I must be doing something wrong and am curious what it is.

Comment: Ui-router is not simpler really...it is just far more robust and scaleable

Comment: @charlietfl I will inspect the request and let you know.  And yes, the url is not redirected in my URL bar, the output is 'Cannot GET /login' in my browser.

Comment: @charlietfl I am getting a 404 Error in my Network tab when navigating to /login.  Do you want to see my directory structure of everything?

Comment: Yeah David you should try fix what you've got. Thats why I only left it as a comment instead of a detailed answer. Good luck with your route provider.

Comment: What url are you using...does it have `#/` in it? If not you are trying to connect to a server page

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks man, adding the hashtag to my URL, I can now access the route.  I figured my relative paths were correct...glad they were.  Obviously I am in the process of learning, but am making some progress.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments by @charlieftl you need to include the `/#/` in your url for angular's route system to work. However, there is also `html5Mode` that you can use to make your original request work too.

Just inject `$locationProvider`, and use:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

You can read more about it:

- [$locationProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider)
- https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

This will allow you to not require the `#` in your urls.